# Comparing contents of a dictionary and txt file

Tags: java, arrays, loops, dictionary, buffer

I am trying to read the contents of a poem txt file (which has spelling mistakes) and compare it to a dictionary in order to filter these mistakes. I eventually want the program to print out all the elements of the txt file which contain spelling mistakes. I am having issues with my nested for loops as I unsure about how to cycle through every string in my dictionary txt file and compare it to my poem txt file.

```
public static String compareFileContents(String poem, String dictionary) 
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{



  char[] buffer = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(poem));
        int bufferLength = (int)(new File(poem).length());
        buffer = new char[bufferLength];
        br1.read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        br1.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }



    String text = new String(buffer);
      String[] poem2 = text.split(" ");

  char[] buffer2 = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new java.io.FileReader(dictionary));
        int bufferLength = (int)(new File(dictionary).length());
        buffer2 = new char[bufferLength];
        br2.read(buffer2, 0, bufferLength);
        br2.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

   String dictionary2 = new String(buffer);
      String[] dictionary3 = dictionary2.split(" ");

      boolean found=false;

     for(int i=0;i<dictionary3.length;i++){
       for(int j=0;j<poem2.length;j++)  {
        if(!poem2[j].equals(dictionary3[i])) {
            System.out.println(poem2[j]);

        }
     }
     }
```

Comment: How exactly are the poem and dictionary files formatted?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: For instance, the poem could be composed of lines of words separated by spaces separated by newlines and the dictionary could be composed of words separated by just newlines. Maybe include an example snippet in your answer from each file to give an idea of the structure.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. My poem is seperated by new lines and spaces and my dictionary is seperated by new lines

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the entire poem is being printed with no regard to the spelling mistakes. I'm very confused about how this could have happened as I followed your instructions exactly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, you just have your nested loops inverted.  You want to first loop over every word in the poem.  Then, for each word of the poem, loop over every word in the dictionary.  If you find a match, continue.  If you loop through the whole dictionary without finding a match to the current poem word, you found a spelling mistake.  You can implement that like this.

You're also splitting by the incorrect delimiter.  Since your poem words are separated by spaces and newlines, you should use a regular expression for splitting by whitespace.  Similarly, since your dictionary words are split by newlines, you should split by newlines.

```
// ...
String[] poem2 = text.split("\\s+");

// ...
String[] dictionary3 = dictionary2.split("\n");

for(int i = 0; i < poem2.length; i++) {
    boolean found = false;
    for(int j = 0; j < dictionary3.length; j++) {
        if(poem2[i].equals(dictionary3[j])) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        System.out.println(poem2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but for whatever reason the misspelled words are not printing out on my console.

Comment: Are the words in the dictionary file separated by spaces?  Are there any newlines in the files?

Comment: Yes it is separated by new lines

Comment: @Abby then you need to `split` by newlines, not spaces.

Comment: Hi I split by new lines and it is printing out correctly spelt words as well as incorrectly spelt words

Answer (score 0):

Here is a late answer it is based around a spell checker written to check spelling in a TextArea
The dictionary can be downloaded [HERE](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) words_alpha.txt works
This is written in Netbeans 8.2 with JavaFX 8
Main Class

```
public class SpellChecker extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("spellchecker.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("spellchecker.css").toExternalForm());
    root.getStyleClass().add("pane");// Code to style Anchor Pane's in CSS
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("Images/s.bmp"));// All Stages have this icon
    stage.setTitle("Spell Checker");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
} 

public class SpellCheckerController implements Initializable {

@FXML Pane spellcheckerPane;
@FXML TextArea txaInput;
@FXML TextField txtMessage,txtReplacementWord,txtWordToReplace;
@FXML ComboBox cboMisspelledWord,cboCorrectSpelling;
@FXML Button btnClose,btnCheckSpelling,btnIgnore,btnReplace;

ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> capture = new ArrayList<>();
String[] strArray;
String searchString;
StringBuilder sb;
String strSF;
String middleChar;
String strEntered;
```

private void populate(){

```
txaInput.setText("Tak the Tz short-term bul buy the hor sve's and see if thi will be cau\n\nNew Laaz abo");
```

}

private void SpellCheck(){

```
txtMessage.setText("Search Complete");

cboMisspelledWord.getItems().clear();

String line = txaInput.getText();
line = line.replaceAll("[=@#$%&()+,!.?<>:|_*;0-9]","");
strArray = line.split("\\s");

for(int X = 0; X < strArray.length;X++){
    strEntered = strArray[X];

boolean found = false;
for(int Y = 0; Y < dictionary.size();Y++){ 
   if(dictionary.get(Y).equalsIgnoreCase(strEntered)){ 
   found = true;
}

}if(found != false){
    capture.add(strEntered);


} 
}

for(int P = 0; P < capture.size();P++){

    String gotIT = capture.get(P); 
    String[] EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY = new String[0];
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, strArray);
    list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(gotIT));
    strArray = list.toArray(EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY); 
    // Code above removes the correct spelled words from ArrayList capture
    // Leaving the misspelled words in strArray then below they are added 
    // to the cboMisspelledWord which then holds all the misspelled words
}

    for(int r = 0; r < strArray.length;r++){
        String A = strArray[r];
        cboMisspelledWord.getItems().add(A);
    }

   if(cboMisspelledWord.getItems().isEmpty()){
        txtMessage.setText("No Misspelled Words");
   }else{
        int n = strArray.length;
        txtMessage.setText("There are "+n+" Misspelled Words");
   }
```

}

```
public void cboCorrectSpelling(){
   ObservableList spell = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
   spell.removeListener((InvalidationListener) cboCorrectSpelling);
}

@FXML
private void getCorrectSpelling(){

    if(cboCorrectSpelling.getValue() != null) {
        String selected = cboCorrectSpelling.getValue().toString();
        txtReplacementWord.setText(selected);
        String testCB = txtWordToReplace.getText();
        boolean isCAP;
        char firstChar = testCB.charAt(0);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(firstChar)) {
        isCAP = true;
        String MakeCapital = selected;
        String firstLetter = MakeCapital.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        String restLetters = MakeCapital.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        txtReplacementWord.setText(firstLetter+restLetters);
    }  
        btnReplace.requestFocus();        
        btnReplace.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:red;");
        txtMessage.setText("Click Mouse to Replace");
    } 
}

public void cboMisspelledWord(){
   ObservableList misspell = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
}

@FXML
private void getMisspelledWord(){
    if(cboMisspelledWord.getValue() != null) {
    String selected = cboMisspelledWord.getValue().toString();
    txtWordToReplace.setText(selected);
    if(selected.contains("\"")|| selected.contains("-")|| selected.contains("'")){
        txtMessage.setText("Manually Replace or Ignore");
        txtReplacementWord.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    }
    cboCorrectSpelling.requestFocus();
    FindCorrectSpelling(); 
}

private void FindCorrectSpelling(){

    if(txtWordToReplace.getText().isEmpty()){
       txtMessage.setText("Select Misspelled Word");
       return;                  
    }

    searchString = txtWordToReplace.getText();

    for(int indexSC = 0; indexSC < dictionary.size();indexSC++){

        String NewSS = txtWordToReplace.getText().toLowerCase();

        int a = NewSS.length();

    if(a < 2){
        txtMessage.setText("Word NOT in Dictionary");
        return;
    }

    int Z;
    if(a == 2){// manage CR was 0
        Z = 2;// was 0
    }else if(a == 3){
        Z = 3;
    }else if(a > 3 && a < 5){
        Z = 4;
    }else if(a >= 5 && a < 8){
        Z = 4;
    }else{
        Z = 5;
    }

    txtMessage.setText("");
    String strS = searchString.substring(0,Z).toLowerCase();
    strSF = strS; 

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    int W = txtWordToReplace.getText().length();
    String frontChar = txtWordToReplace.getText().substring(0, 1).toLowerCase();
    String endChar = txtWordToReplace.getText().substring(W - 2, W);   
    if(W > 7){
        middleChar = txtWordToReplace.getText().substring(W-5, W);
    }else{
        middleChar = txtWordToReplace.getText().substring(W-1, W); 
    }

    dictionary.stream().filter(s -> s.startsWith(strSF)
        || s.startsWith(frontChar, 0)
        && s.length() > 1 && s.length() <= W+3 
        && s.endsWith(endChar)
        && s.startsWith(frontChar)
        && s.contains(middleChar))
        .forEach(list :: add);  

    for(int X = 0; X < list.size();X++){
        String strA = (String) list.get(X);
        sort(list);
        cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().add(strA);

    }
    break;
}   
}

@FXML
private void onClick(){
    onReplace();
}

@FXML
private void onPress(KeyEvent ev) throws IOException{
    KeyCode kc = ev.getCode();
    if(kc == KeyCode.ENTER){
        onReplace();
    }   
}

@FXML
private void onReplace(){

    if(txtReplacementWord.getText().isEmpty() || txtWordToReplace.getText().length() == 0){
        txtMessage.setText("Enter the Replacement Word");
        return;
    }

    if(txtReplacementWord.getText().length() >= 1){
      String fL = txtReplacementWord.getText().substring(0, 1); 

    if(fL.contains(" ")){
        txtMessage.setText("No Leading Spaces");
        return;
    }
    }

    if(txtWordToReplace.getText().length() >= 1){
      String fL = txtWordToReplace.getText().substring(0, 1); 

    if(fL.contains(" ")){
        txtMessage.setText("No Leading Spaces HERE");
        return;
    }
    }


Map<String, String> replacements = new HashMap<>();
replacements.put(txtWordToReplace.getText(), txtReplacementWord.getText());

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\S+");

    String text = txaInput.getText();
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    int lastEnd = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int startIndex = matcher.start();
        if (startIndex > lastEnd) {

            sb.append(text.substring(lastEnd, startIndex));
        }


        String group = matcher.group();
        String result = replacements.get(group);
        sb.append(result == null ? group : result);

        lastEnd = matcher.end();
    }
    sb.append(text.substring(lastEnd));
    txaInput.setText(sb.toString());
    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().remove(txtWordToReplace.getText());
    txtMessage.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear(); 
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();
    btnReplace.setStyle("-fx-text-fill:black;");

    if(cboMisspelledWord.getItems().isEmpty()){
        onCheckSpelling();
    }
}

@FXML
private void onIgnore(){

    if(cboMisspelledWord.getItems().isEmpty() || txtWordToReplace.getText().length() == 0 || txtWordToReplace.getText().contains(" ")){
        txtMessage.setText("Nothing to Ignore");
        return;
    }
    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().remove(txtWordToReplace.getText()); 
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear();
    if(cboMisspelledWord.getItems().isEmpty()){
        onCheckSpelling();
    }
}

@FXML
private void onCheckSpelling(){
    String line = txaInput.getText();
    if(line.length() == 0){
       txtMessage.setText("No Data Entered");
       return;
    }
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear();
    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().clear();

    SpellCheck();
}

@FXML 
private void onClose(){  
    System.exit(0);
    Platform.exit();
}

private void onLoad() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    Instant namesStart = Instant.now();

    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/A_WORDS/dictionary.txt"))) {

        for(String line = input.readLine(); 
            line != null;
            line = input.readLine()) {
            dictionary.add(line);
        }
        input.close();
    }

    int gl = dictionary.size();
    System.out.println("## gl "+gl);
    for(int X = 0; X < dictionary.size();X++){
        String D = dictionary.get(X);
        //System.out.println("#### Dictionary "+D);
    if(X == gl-1){
    long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
    System.out.println("!!!!! time2 "+time2/1000000);
    txtMessage.setText("Loaded in "+time2/1000000+" ms");
    Instant namesEnd = Instant.now();
    long timeElapsedNames = Duration.between(namesStart, namesEnd).toMillis();
    System.out.println("Name time: " + timeElapsedNames + "ms");
    }

    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    spellcheckerPane.getStyleClass().add("pane");
    populate();

    try {
        onLoad();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SpellCheckerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="spellcheckerPane" onMouseClicked="#onClick" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SpellChecker.SpellCheckerController">
   <children>
      <TextArea fx:id="txaInput" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="28.0" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="720.0" wrapText="true">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font></TextArea>
      <TextField fx:id="txtWordToReplace" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="254.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="txtReplacementWord" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="349.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <TextField fx:id="txtMessage" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="44.0" layoutY="433.0" prefWidth="320.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </TextField>
      <ComboBox fx:id="cboMisspelledWord" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="219.0" onAction="#getMisspelledWord" prefWidth="215.0" visibleRowCount="5" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="cboCorrectSpelling" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="286.0" onAction="#getCorrectSpelling" prefWidth="215.0" />
      <Button fx:id="btnClose" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="50.0" layoutY="510.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClose" text="CLOSE">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnCheckSpelling" layoutX="482.0" layoutY="510.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onCheckSpelling" text="CheckSpelling">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnIgnore" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="361.0" layoutY="510.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onIgnore" text="Ignore">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="btnReplace" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="660.0" layoutY="510.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onReplace" onKeyPressed="#onPress" text="Replace">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="47.0" layoutY="316.0" text="Replacement Word">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="222.0" text="Word to Replace">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="45.0" layoutY="401.0" text="Messages">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="380.0" layoutY="222.0" text="Misspelled Words">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label focusTraversable="false" layoutX="393.0" layoutY="289.0" text="Correct Spelling">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```